# Automatic icon selector according to the file i selected in <a href> tag

Tags: c#, html

I wonder how could I improve these code that it will automatically recognize file in the folder "/Doc/Projekti/<%=dat%>" and chose the right icon from "/Img/image.png". In this folder, I have icons for pdf, xls, word,... 
All these icons are in png format. Here is my code I currently using but on all files that code find is  now pdf icon

```
<%  
    string adresa = (string)Application["naslov"];
    string adresa1 = adresa + "doc\\Projekti";
    var t=2;
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(adresa1);
    FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
    foreach (FileInfo dat in files){
        var test=dat;
        if(test.ToString() != "Thumbs.db"){

    %>
<a  href="/Doc/Projekti/<%=dat%>" style="color:#6c8230; padding: 0 0 10px 10px; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><img src="/Img/pdf.png" style="border: 0px" alt="PDF"><%=dat%></a><BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assignment of the icon, call a function that gets the file name as an input and return the matching png icon according to the file extension.